# How to write a C++ regex expression that recognizes selected float or int number in the string based on some criteria?

Tags: c++, regex

Hello stack overflow fellows,

Here is an example string:

```
"X1X: 7, Y1Y: 8.000, Z1Z:-8, W1W: -0.2"
```

I am trying to get the results from variables X1X, Y1Y, Z1Z, W1W using regex in C++.

I tried: `[+-]?[0-9]*[.][0-9]+`,
which would not give me int 7 from X1X

Also tried: `[-+]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+`,
but which would also give me "1"s contained in "X1X", "Y1Y", "Z1Z" and "W1W".

I do not want to write extra lines to filter the result from my regex due to the purpose of my function in the code. I believe regex can be super long and fancy to do the job. Can anyone help me out on this please?

Comment: You need `[+-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b` or `[+-]?(?:\b[0-9]+)?\.?[0-9]+\b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want a regex at all, because the regex is going to capture those numbers as strings and then you'll have to do a separate step to convert the strings to numbers.  Instead, you can just do something like this:

```
char myString[] = "X1X: 7, Y1Y: 8.000, Z1Z:-8, W1W: -0.2";

int x1x, z1z;
float y1y, w1w;

std::sscanf(myString, "X1X: %d, Y1Y: %f, Z1Z: %d, W1W: %f", &x1x, &y1y, &z1z, &w1w);
```

If you really want to do a regex capture, you can do it like so:

```
std::string myString = "X1X: 7, Y1Y: 8.000, Z1Z:-8, W1W: -0.2";

std::regex regex(
  "X1X: ([+-]?[0-9]*), Y1Y: ([+-]?[0-9]*(?:\\.[0-9]*)?), Z1Z:([+-]?[0-9]*), W1W: ([+-]?[0-9]*(?:\\.[0-9]*)?)");

std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;

bool success = std::regex_match(myString, results, regex);
```

This puts the results in `results[1]` through `results[4]`.  (Of course this requires exactly the same spacing as in your additional string, so you probably want to throw some `*`s in there.

Comment: +1 for "You probably don't want a regex at all ...". Among the hundreds of questions here that ask about how to write a regular expression to solve a particular problem, I've only seen one where a regular expression was actually a good solution.